# Bash - Remove domain/subdomains from file B, if main domain is in file A (or piped)

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I would like to be able to use a piped input or reference file of domains (**file B**) to remove each domain and it's subdomains from **file A**

I can't use `grep "bbc.co.uk"`, for example, as this would include entries such as `cbbc.co.uk`.

I have tried to use a while read loop to iterate through **file B**, running `grep -E "^([^.\s]+\.)*${escaped_domain}$" fileA` to identify both domains and subdomains but this is very, very slow with the amount of comparisons required.

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps using awk?

**File B (or piped input)**

~30k lines

```
bbc.co.uk
amazon.co.uk
doubleclick.net
```

**File A**

~150k+ lines

```
123123.test.bbc.co.uk
123434.rwr.amazon.co.uk
ads.bbc.co.uk
adsa.23432.doubleclick.net
amazon.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
cbbc.co.uk
damazon.co.uk
fsdfsfs.doubleclick.net
test.amazon.co.uk
test.bbc.co.uk
test.damazon.co.uk
```

**Desired output:**

```
cbbc.co.uk
damazon.co.uk
test.damazon.co.uk
```

**Current method (different input with grep/regexps)**

```
# Convert input: address=/test.com/ -> ^([^.\s]+\.)*test\.com$
regexList=$(cat fileB | 
    sed 's/\./\\./g' |
    awk -F '/' {'print "^([^.\s]+\.)*"$2"$"'})

while read -r regex; do
    grep -E $regex filaA
done <<< "$regexList"
```

Comment: *I can't use grep "bbc.co.uk", for example, as this would include entries such as cbbc.co.uk* You can use `grep -Eo "\bbbc.co.uk\b`

Comment: I have tried using word boundaries before. Unfortunately this matches things like `my-bbc.co.uk` making it a little over sensitive.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the output should not include those domains as `doubleclick.net` is in `file B`. `adsa.23432.doubleclick.net` is a subdomain of `doubleclick.net`, so should not be outputted.

Comment: We are easily confused. Naming your first input file B and your second one A is unnecessary obfuscation. It's hard enough to figure out what someone needs to do and how to help them without also having to remember that the **first** input file in the question is named `fileB`! Don't change it now of course or it'll make things worse but next time....

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        gsub(/[^^]/,"[&]")
        gsub(/\^/,"\\^")
        doms["(^|[.])"$0"$"]
        next
    }
    {
        for (dom in doms) {
            if ($0 ~ dom) {
                next
            }
        }
        print
    }
' fileB fileA
cbbc.co.uk
damazon.co.uk
test.damazon.co.uk
```

or with a pipe:

```
$ cat fileB | awk '...' - fileA
```

If fileB is small enough then you don't need an array you can just build up and test 1 regexp for all domains:

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { doms = "(^|[.])(" $0; next }
    NR==FNR {
        gsub(/[^^]/,"[&]")
        gsub(/\^/,"\\^")
        doms = doms "|" $0
        next
    }
    FNR==1 { doms = doms ")$" }
    $0 !~ doms
' fileB fileA
cbbc.co.uk
damazon.co.uk
test.damazon.co.uk
```

The 2 `gsub()`s in each script are ensuring that all regexp metacharacters in the domains are treated as literal characters instead. See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for details on why and how that works.

Comment: Thanks - I am giving it a try; It does seem to take a long while before printing result in comparison to the use of`grep -E`. Is this to be expected when processing files of this size?

Comment: Generally, no. The first one might take a BIT longer since it's looking through every domain in fileB one at a time for every line in fileA but it's looking for a simple regexp each iteration rather than looking for a complex regexp all at once so the time difference shouldn't be much, the second one shouldn't take any more time as it's doing exactly the same thing that grep -E does (with assumptions on my part about how you're using grep -E!). They should both print the FIRST result quickly either way. You sure you don't have it hung waiting for input?

Comment: Definitely sure it's not waiting for input - It seems to be really slow with large input files. Is there any way that I can provide you with my `file A` and `file B` testing? I have included in the original post my current method; please note that the input file (B) for this method is in slightly different format to my desired format.

Comment: Do you know it's not waiting for input because it does produce output or something else? No, I don't have time to do any more with it so I won't download files to test with, sorry. Have you tried your current shell-loop-with-greps and my awk script on a smaller file? I'd actually be shocked if that while-read-grep loop wasn't an order of magnitude **slower** than the awk script and it's fragile in several ways so I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't actually using all of your regexps and/or is otherwise producing incorrect output (see what @triplee **actually** suggested).

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the first file into a set of regular expressions for what to remove:

```
sed 's/[][\\.^$*+?()]/\\&/g;s/.*/^([^.]+\\.)*&$/' fileB
```

The output is a sequence of regular expressions you can pass to `grep -vE`:

```
... | grep -vEf - fileA
```

There are limits to how much `grep -Ef` can keep in memory in one go, but 30k expressions is probably within limits on modern hardware. In the worst case, split `fileA` in half and run the process twice.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, hadn't seen that before, placement of backslash in a character class had to be changed. I thought I was being extra careful by doubling the backslash but that wasn't helping at all. This might still not be entirely portable.

Comment: Looks like it'd be portable to me. The only thing I wonder about is whether or not you can really just escape all of those chars. In another question I participated in about escaping regexp metachars we ended up putting all chars except `^` inside bracket expressions and only escaped `^` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001) but I don't remember under what conditions just escaping them all was inadequate. Maybe it was just because we weren't assuming EREs and so had to worry about accidentally enabling ERE metachars? idk...